# Using JS to create a dynamic seating chart

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to add another line of code to this code to get the 'green' cells to switch back to 'yellow' after a given amount of time.  would I add another function or add another else statement?  Is it possible to nest the utilities.sleep function in one more time and only trigger it if a greater than condition is met?

In addition if I wanted this to go across rather than columns and pinpoint specific cells that represent tables.  Think of a hostess with her seating chart could this be done in the offset clause for rows. and could this code also be run on another sheet and just show the checkboxes to the hostess while the color change and time stamp are run on another sheet?

Right now I have created a time stamp that only satisfies 2 conditions. Un clicked go to green and clicked go to red after a certain amount of time. If I need to create another function who would I run both functions or do I just add more var to the current function to include satisfying my 3rd condition of green to yellow showing a stag-net table ready to be seating while red is showing they have been at the table a long time but its still occupied

```
 function onEdit(e) {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // the active sheet (no need to check if the sheet == sheet1 as the active sheet will always be the one that's being edited)
    var r = e.range; // the range of the edited cell
    var c = r.getColumn(); // the column of the range
    var timeDelay = 5; // number in seconds
    var checkbox = r.getValue(); // the value of the checkbox after being 
    edited
    var date = new Date(); // the date for the timestamp

    if (c == 3 && checkbox === true) { // if the checkbox has been checked, 
    change the color to red
    var nextCell = r.offset(0,1);
    Utilities.sleep(timeDelay * 100); // Utilities.sleep takes a number in 
    milliseconds
    nextCell.setValue(date).setBackground("red");
    } else if (c == 3 && checkbox === false){ // unchecked switch to green
    var nextCell = r.offset(0,1);
    nextCell.setValue(date).setBackground("green"); 
    Utilities.sleep(timeDelay * 1);
  }
 }
```

any time I try to add another else statement I can not and if I add another condition to the green else if to get it to turn to yellow after x amount of minutes it skips go to green and goes right to yellow instead of vacillating between the two

Comment: What do you mean by "I try to add another else statement I can not "?

Comment: adding another else statement in that function to provide the code to return back to yellow when a cell has been idle and unoccupied aka the check box not checked  for x amount of minutes changing green to yellow

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var r = e.range;
  var c = r.columnStart;
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
  if(e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value) {
    switch (Number(e.value)) {
      case 1:
        e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(date).setBackground("red");
        break;
      case 2:
        e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(date).setBackground("green"); 
        break;
      default:
        e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(date).setBackground("yellow"); 
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey cooper thank you for this code - for each case would I then need to add the delay timer and if statements based on the check boxes - if not how else would the cell determine which color to be and when?  If I am missing something I apologize I am still new to JS thank you again!

Comment: I didn't use check boxes, I used validation from a list of items i.e. 1,2,3.  And I didn't really understand the point of the time delays.  Keep in mind simple triggers have to complete in 30 seconds.

Comment: The point of the time delay is to visually see when a table has been occupied for a certain amount of time to make it very easy to decipher for the hostess

Comment: I think it would be better to find a solution that doesn't slow down the onEdit process.  Perhaps outlining the borders.

Comment: If you would like to provide a link to something please make it public.

Comment: Nope. Not public

Comment: Ok finally this one should work  - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JdfJNL6Q-yYoF-0w9MPE6RebjmtLjyvTc76K0YpMrH8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please let me know if that is still not accessible thanks!